# Cement material for holding objects together?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Is there any way to create a material that could hold two objects together? I don't want to use armature, because I am creating more of a building for a game, not a charecter with joints.I also don't want to join the objects, because I want to allow for the objects to seperate at some level of force. Is there anyone who could suggest something to me? Thanks!

These are my Rigid body constraint settings.
[image]

Comment: You could use rigid body constraints, see the wiki: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Rigid_Body_Joint

Comment: For some reason this is not working. My constraint settings are above. Is there anything I can do that will make the constraint stronger?

Comment: Those settings are for the rigid body simulator in the viewport. The game engine settings are a bit different.. Are you trying to do this in the game engine or the viewport (to be rendered in BI or cycles)?

Comment: Mine was using Blender Render (Blender Internal)

Comment: So.. you are not using the game engine?

Comment: No. I saw that there were two places to use the rigid body constraints, and I guess this was the wrong one.

Comment: If you are not using the game engine, then you are in the right place. And you can use *breakable constraints* with the viewport physics, as a matter of fact the option is in your screenshot :)